# Something that defines or describes bilateral movement/direction

Tags: single-word-requests

The Hudson River can flow both upwards and downwards.
An internet connection allows the download and upload of data.

Is there a more suitable or alternate word to bilateral?

Thank you.

Comment: _bidirectional_, perhaps?

Comment: Also *two-way*.

Comment: Both suggestions suit different contexts. Thank you